# Getting Custom Route Names from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do something that, I'm sure, will turn out to be easy. I have an API service with a custom route name and I'm trying to get custom route name from a view. Here is the relevant API code:

```
public class ImageController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/v1/images/Upload/Profile"]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult UploadProfileImage([FromBody] ImageUpload upload)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        // ...

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant code from my view:

```
<!-- My HTML Code -->
<!-- ... -->

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'What do I put here ??'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I am trying to figure out what I put in the `url` section to make it map to my api route.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method:

```
public static string GetRouteName(this Route route)
{
     if(route != null)
          return route.DataToken.GetRouteName();

     throw new Exception("Invalid Route.");
}

public static string GetRouteName(this RouteValueDictionary routeValues) 
{
    if (routeValues == null) {
        return null;
    }

    object routeName = null;
    routeValues.TryGetValue("__RouteName", out routeName);
    return routeName as string;
}
```

Then you would simply call it within your Api.  I would either directly inject the data to the view or pass it via your model.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. Mvc contains a method for doing this called [HttpRouteUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.httprouteurl(v=vs.118).aspx)